# UV overlays disappear in edit mode and only shows metadata option

Tags: texturing, uv

I just started working at a new company with a new laptop and I downloaded the automatic Blender version, 3.6. I made a 3D-model and usually when I unwrap, I can easily open and use the display stretch option to see how much stretching is happening on the UV. However, if I select an object and start unwrapping, the overlay options are gone as well as the overlay button. If I don't select any models, the overlay option appears but only shows the metadata option. Does anyone know if a setting is wrong or if this is an issue with this blender version and what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. In the bottom image in your question, to the left of the View menu button there is an icon with a dropdown. Is this from a third party addon and could it be causing the problem? Either deactivate the addon and close and reopen Blender and try unwrapping, or try unwrapping this after using File->Defaults->Load Factory Settings and see what happens. I don't have any problems with missing items when unwrapping in Blender 3.6.9 using Windows 10. Also, I don't understand what you mean by the "automatic" Blender version. Do you mean the version with an installer? What OS are you using?